# PHP - On the fly form feedback?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I've got a basic registration form on my website and I was just wondering what the best method would be to give feedback on the entered fields automatically without having to press the submit button.

For example when a user enters their username, how can I get the the system to tell them if the username has been taken before they press the submit button?

Regards

Comment: Your question is too broad. The answer is basically Ajax. You should have path the return the usernames and you can then check them against the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options.  For any given piece of feedback you can:

1. Provide the page with all of the information it needs to provide the feedback, likely in JavaScript code.  Then when the user enters a value that code would perform its calculations and react accordingly.
2. Query the server via AJAX to run server-side calculations for providing feedback.

For example:

In the first scenario, you might want to check against a small static list of possible values.  So you might emit those values into JavaScript when the page loads:

```
var possibleValues = [ 'firstValue', 'secondValue', 'thirdValue' ];
```

(I know, a `select` would make more sense here anyway, but this is just for the sake of example.)

Then when the input changes, your JavaScript code would check the input against the known values and respond to the user accordingly.

In the second scenario, perhaps there are *many* possible values, or perhaps you don't want the user to *see* all possible values (such as with a username) and only want to tell them if it's valid or not.  In that case you'd make an AJAX request with the information provided by the user.  Maybe something like:

```
$.post( "checkvalue.php", { name: $('#someInput').val() })
 .done(function(data) {
     // check the result from the server and respond to the user accordingly
 });
```

In either case, you're writing JavaScript code to respond to the user's input.  The only difference is where that JavaScript code gets its data or where the calculations on the data are performed.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use JavaScript to do this.  You can either do it on `keyup` or on `blur` (at least those would probably work the best).  If you want feedback while typing, use `keyup`.  `blur` or would work if the user can unfocus (move to the next field) first.  The keyup event may look something like this:

```
var lastTime = 0;
input.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
    clearTimeout(lastTime);

    // throttle input -- only check after 500 seconds
    setTimeout(function () {
        ajax.get("username-check.php?name=" + this.value)
            .done(function (used) {
                if (used) {
                    this.classList.add("error");
                }
            }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this), 500);
});
```

Comment: Of note, especially if this is a large system, you'll probably want to put some throttling mechanisms on it if you go with `keyup`, such as only query after a certain number of characters, and only after so many characters or a certain length pause in typing. Otherwise, you'll end up with a lot of largely useless queries (like looking for "a").

Comment: Thanks, thats a good point. As the lump of text above the code on this answer states, i'll probably user blur so the ajax doesn't run so often :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `onchange` event of the field to use ajax to send a request to the server. Then retrieve the response and display the result to the user.

Example jQuery :

```
    $('#username').on('change', function() {
        //Create object to pass
        var o = new Object();
        o.UserName = $('#username').val();

        //Stringify object into JSON
        var x = JSON.stringify(o);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'phpURL',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: x,
            success: function (data) {
                //Display Results (i.e Name taken / Name available)
            },
            error: function (ajaxrequest) {
                //Display a helpful error to the user or log this error for your use.
                //ajaxrequest.responseText
            }
        })
    });
```